# Copy strings inside the same file

Tags: bash, sed, replace, find

How can i copy strings inside the same file under conditions?

I have many files like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Message.
 *
 * NOTE: this file must be saved in UTF-8 encoding.
 */
return [
    'To copy' => '',
    'No to copy' => 'Not to copy as already filed',
];
```

I would like to recursively go trough all files inside a folder, search for strings that are empty (see **"To copy"** on the example) and then copy the text from left to right inside the `''` **if** this one is empty.

In the example, the first line should be copied as the right `''` is empty, but not the second line, as the right `''` is already filled (by the same content or not).

So it becomes:

```
<?php
/**
 * Message.
 *
 * NOTE: this file must be saved in UTF-8 encoding.
 */
return [
    'To copy' => 'To copy',
    'No to copy' => 'Not to copy as already filed',
];
```

Hope i am clear. i know how to `sed`, `find` and `replace` inside a file, but this is the first time i came across this specific case.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***bash*** + ***sed*** approach:

Creating `replace_empty.sh` (test name) bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /tmp/test/*.php 
do 
    sed -i -E "s/^([[:space:]]*)('[^']+') => '[[:space:]]*',\$/\1\2 => \2,/g" $f
done
```

Replace file path `/tmp/test/*.php` with your actual path

*sed* options:

`-i` - to modify file in place

`-E` - to allow extended regular expressions

`('[^']+')` - captures *key* name

`\1` and `\2` - point to the 1st and 2nd captured group respectively

---

***Usage:***

```
bash replace_empty.sh
```

Comment: you could as well pass `/tmp/test/*.php` directly to `sed` instead of using for-loop..

Comment: @Sundeep, I saw that "long" line (if there long file path). I had come to a more readable variant. Besides, we could add some other processing along with sed substitution

Comment: oh okay... but do quote the variable... `"$f"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've just missed the comma at the end ;)

`sed -i -E "s/^([[:space:]]*)('[^']+') => '[[:space:]]*',\$/\1\2 => \2,/g" $f`